# get list product Nest with REST call

Tags: nest-api

I am trying to develop an c/c++ app using the newly published NEST REST api but bit lost with their native documentation.
i can't find how to get a list of all product of one user

i just find how to get information about one product using his product_id and product_secret to get pin code and access token hen i can just communicate with one product

```
system("curl -v -L -H \"Authorization: Bearer c...." -X GET \"https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostats/\" >structure.json");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url you are using is only asking for thermostats. Make a GET call with a valid token to either `https://developer-api.nest.com` or `https://developer-api.nest.com/devices`

Also make sure all the permissions are enabled in the Nest clients Product page